# How much do Spanish dogs really bark?

Tags: spain, security, pets

I'm hoping to spend a few months in northern Spain and have just read a book about the Camino de Santiago in which the (Norwegian) author remarked that Spanish dogs bark "a lot" because they are for protection rather than companionship. Obviously it's a subjective judgment, but I am pretty sensitive to ambient noise, so I want to know more about Spanish norms.

Is there in fact more dog barking in Spain than in other countries? Can I expect to hear them in Spanish cities, or only in the countryside? Can I do anything to not end up renting a place next to a barking dog? (Staying in a high-rise does come to mind.)

Comment: Did you really believe they bred a specific dog race for Spain? They have the same dogs as anywhere, and they bark the same as anywhere.

Comment: @Aganju No. This question is about societal norms. Dogs kept as pets are often much quieter than those used to defend a property.

Comment: It is quite common in rural areas of Spain to have dorks to protect the house. So it is normal to be walking through a path and get some loud barks. Since Camino de Santiago goes often through rural areas, this can happen (often). I don't know if this happens often in other countries.

Answer (score 2):

There's some science that [animals are louder in cities](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/02/120222132930.htm), actually, to compensate for the ambient noise, not the reverse.

Dogs can also [understand each other](https://www.psychologytoday.com/nz/blog/canine-corner/201211/how-dogs-bark-in-different-languages) regardless of where they're from, so it's not like 'Spanish barking' is particularly different.

Spain has [the 6th highest number of dogs](https://www.statista.com/statistics/414956/dog-population-european-union-eu-by-country/) in the EU, and it being a smaller country than some of the others above it, might make them seem more frequent.

However, other than that it's most likely just subjective views of areas people went to in Spain, if they were perhaps, unused to the sound of dogs barking.